# Owl carousel still transitions when only 1 slide in carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, transition, owl-carousel

I wonder if anyone could help with this. I am using carousel in a CMS and would like the ability for the customer to sometimes only have 1 slide if they so wish. However if only 1 slide is there the fade transition still occurs so it basically transitions to itself. Is there any way to stop the carousel transitioning when there is only 1 slide? I am surprised that this is not a built in function as it has been with other carousels I have used.

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
    <h2><umbraco:Item field="bigMessage" stripParagraph="true" convertLineBreaks="true" runat="server" /></h2>
    <p><umbraco:Item field="messageSubtext" stripParagraph="true" convertLineBreaks="true" runat="server" /></p>
    <umbraco:image runat="server" field="bannerImage" />
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<style>
#owl-demo .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

    navigation: false,
    stopOnHover: true,
    paginationSpeed: 1000,
    autoPlay: 5000,
    goToFirstSpeed: 2000,
    autoHeight : true,
    transitionStyle:"fade",
    singleItem: true

  // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
  // items : 1, 
  // itemsDesktop : false,
  // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
  // itemsTablet: false,
  // itemsMobile : false

  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 17):

*For the new beta version see below*

---

## Owl Carousel 1.3.2

In *this* version, it doesn't seem that the plugin has a setting for this. You can do this on your own, either before or after the plugin has been initialized.

**Option 1 - before plugin initialization**

The best approach would be for you to detect this situation before initializing the plugin altogether.

For example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $owlContainer = $('#owl-demo');
    $owlSlides    = $owlContainer.children('div');

     // More than one slide - initialize the carousel
    if ($owlSlides.length > 1) {
        $owlContainer.owlCarousel({
         // options go here
        });
     // Only one slide - do something else
    } else {
        //...
    }
});
```

**Option 2 - after plugin initialization**

It might be the case that you're relying on the plugin to also style and dynamically adjust the item. In this situation, you can detect there's only one slide after initialization and then stop the transitions. You can do this with the `afterInit` callback and the `stop` method.

For example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#owl-demo').owlCarousel({
         // other options go here
         //...,
         afterInit: function() {
            $owlContainer = $('#owl-demo');
            $owlSlides    = $owlContainer.children('div');
              // Only one slide - stop the carousel
            if ($owlSlides.length == 1) {
               $owlContainer.stop();
            }
         }
    });
});
```

---

## Owl Carousel 2 Beta

In this new revamped version of the plugin, the API has been completely replaced. The same approaches are still possible, but the implementation is a little different.

**Option 1 - before plugin initialization**

The new API now includes an option named `autoplay`, which allows to directly control the carousel's behavior once it's initialized. By default this option is set to `false`, but we can set it as we please according to the number of slides.

For example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $owlContainer = $('#owl-demo');
    $owlSlides    = $owlContainer.children('div');
    owlAutoPlay   = $owlSlide.length > 1;   

    $('#owl-demo').owlCarousel({
        // other options go here
        //...,
        autoplay: owlAutoPlay
    }
});
```

Alternatively, according to the number of slides, we can also choose to not initialize the plugin altogether, as we did in the previous version (see *option 1* above).

**Option 2 - after plugin initialization**

As in the previous version, if you must initialize the plugin (and if you must have the `autoplay` option set to `true)`, you can also stop the carousel after initialization. However, in this version the initialization callback option is now named `onInitialized`. Also, there's no direct `.stop()` method. Instead you will need to trigger the `autoplay.stop.owl` event of the carousel.

For example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#owl-demo').owlCarousel({
        // Other options go here
        // ...,
        onInitialized: function() {
            if ($('#owl-demo').children().length == 1) {
                 $('#owl-demo').trigger('autoplay.stop.owl');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can do: $("#owl-demo").stop(); but the slides keep on sliding

Comment: Just to make sure - you've changed `#owl-demo` to your own relevant selector, right?

Comment: @DavidKarlsson Are you by any chance using the new beta version, Owl Carousel 2? If so, this appears to be a revamped plugin with a very different API, that doesn't have the `.stop()` method altogether. I will update the answer to include this version as well.

Comment: @DavidKarlsson Updated the answer to include the new beta version as well.

Comment: I had to use $owlSlides = $owlContainer.find(".owl-item"); instead of children() with just .item

Comment: @scotta7exander This obviously depends on your specific markup. If the items are not direct descendants of the main container, then you will need to use the  `find` method.

Comment: write autoPlay not autoplay

Answer (score 3):

You can check if there is 1 item in your carousel and activate 'autoplay' or not. In your case it will be like below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

    navigation: false,
    stopOnHover: true,
    paginationSpeed: 1000,
    goToFirstSpeed: 2000,
    autoHeight : true,
    transitionStyle:"fade",
    singleItem: true
    autoPlay: $("#owl-demo > div").length > 1 ? 5000 : false

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this instead since I am already using exports for setting stuff up:

```
exports.setup = function ($elems, options) {
    if (!!!$elems.length) {return false;}
    options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
    if (!!options.lazyLoad) {
        // See http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html
        $elems.find('img').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('owl-lazy').data('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        });
    }
    //Disable autoplay for "one banner only" carousels:
     if($elems.find('img').length<2){
         options.autoplay=false;
    }

    $elems.owlCarousel(options);
        return $elems;
    };
    head.ready(function() {
        onload_window();
    });

   return exports;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function headerSlider(owlElementID){
    var autoPlay = 5000;
    if (!$(owlElementID).length){
        return false;
    }
    if ($(owlElementID).children().length <2) {
        autoPlay = false;
    }
    $(owlElementID).owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: autoPlay
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the problem with Owl Carousel and only one item is that the item doesn't show if you want the carousel to be looped.

Below is some code you should put before the carousel is initiated, I've added a show and hide of the nav option as well - because you don't want to show navigation elements for one "unlooped" slide:

```
// Calculate number of Slides
var totalItems = $('.item').length;

// If there is only one slide
if (totalItems == 1) {

    // Set loop option variable to false
    var isLooped = false;

    // Set nav option variable to false
    var isNav = false;

} else {

    // Set loop option variable to true
    var isLooped = true;

    // Set loop option variable to true
    var isNav = true;
}

// Initiate Carousel
$('.hpSlider').owlCarousel({
    //add in your dynamic variables to your options
    loop: isLooped,
    nav:isNav,
    // then any other options...
    margin:0,
    video:true,        
    mouseDrag:false,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:3500,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    navSpeed:1300,
    autoplaySpeed:1300,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert an if/else statement in the script part of banner.tlp like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var onOff = "<?php echo sizeof($banners); ?>";

if(onOff !== "1") { 
  onOff = 5000;
} else {
  onOff = false;
}

<!--
$('#banner<?php echo $module; ?>').owlCarousel({
items: 6,
autoPlay: onOff,
singleItem: true,
navigation: true,
navigationText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-5x"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-5x"></i>'],
pagination: true,
transitionStyle: 'fade'
});
-->
</script>
```

It works well with the version of owl carousel that is included in Opencart 2.2.0.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true

      // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
      // items : 1, 
      // itemsDesktop : false,
      // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      // itemsTablet: false,
      // itemsMobile : false

  });

});
```